# Viewing Javascript source in Safari Web Inspector in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

My iOS app includes a UIWebView which runs some Javascript. I am able to attach Safari web inspector to my apps UIWebView instance and have the debugger invoked when a breakpoint is hit, however I am not able to view the actual javascript code.

I am able to see the variables and the call stack, but the source code window is blank.

Is there something that needs to be done in order to make the source code visible?

Switching to the DOM tree view does show the contents of the page, but this is not source level javascript debugging.

Is it possible to actually have the source code for the Javascript being debugged visible in the web inspector?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the code is not visible is because I was making use of the loadHTMLString method on the UIWebView.

Making use of a file URL and loadRequest to load the request allows for the code to become visible.